# Insert image in wkhtml to pdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

Hi I am using wkhtml to pdf method to genearte a pdf , I need to insert a image in my Pdf Header but i dont want to show the PDF header Image in my HTML page. How can i take direct image for my PDF Header.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

probably it could be reached via this:

```
$pdf->addPage('<html><div id="header">AHOJ</div></html>');
$pdf->addPage('/path/to/your.html');
```